# Use C++/CLI Library in C++ native code and how to link

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli

I want to use some code that executes a http-post, and because I'm not too familiar with c++ and what libraries you can use, and I am probably too dumb to get libcurl and curlpp to work, I found a link explaining how to use the .net version.

Alright so I created a class. Header File:

```
public ref class Element
{
public:
    Element();
    virtual ~Element();
    void ExecuteCommand();
};
```

Class file:

```
#include "Element.h"


Element::Element()
{
}


Element::~Element()
{
    Console::WriteLine("deletion");
}


void Element::ExecuteCommand(){
    HttpWebRequest^ request = dynamic_cast<HttpWebRequest^>(WebRequest::Create("http://www.google.com"));

    request->MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
    request->MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;

    request->Credentials = gcnew NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
    HttpWebResponse^ response = dynamic_cast<HttpWebResponse^>(request->GetResponse());
    Console::WriteLine("Content length is {0}", response->ContentLength);
    Console::WriteLine("Content type is {0}", response->ContentType);

    // Get the stream associated with the response.
    Stream^ receiveStream = response->GetResponseStream();

    // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
    StreamReader^ readStream = gcnew StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding::UTF8);
    Console::WriteLine("Response stream received.");
    Console::WriteLine(readStream->ReadToEnd());
    response->Close();
    readStream->Close();

}
```

If I set the configuration type of this project to Application (exe), and create a new .cpp file where I create an Instance of this Element it works fine.

But my question is: Is it possible to create a .dll/.lib Library from this project and use it in a C++ project without CLI? (I don't want to use ^ for pointers :( )

Even if it's not possible, I have another problem.
When I link the library in a C++/CLI project. I get

```
unresolved token (06000001) Element::.ctor
unresolved token (06000002) Element::~Element
unresolved token (06000003) Element::ExecuteCommand
3 unresolved externals
```

the code for main.cpp in the second project is just the following:

```
#include <Element.h>

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can write standard C++ in a project that is compiled with CLI options just fine, but you can't use C++/CLI directly in C++ code compiled without that option.

Comment: Hmya, that's not going to go anywhere.  If you don't want to use ^ then you ought to stick with your plan and *not* #include a file that contains ^.  Using a non-trivial object model written in managed code from a native program requires the clr hosting api or COM.

Comment: Alright, so let's stick with the ^ for now. But if I set the settings of Project 1 to be static Lib (create .lib file) when I include a folder with the `Element.h` in the `C++->Additional Include Dirs` and the lib folder in `Linker->Include` and add `MyAPI.lib`, why do I get the unresolved tokens?

Comment: Because managed code cannot be linked, it is always dynamically bound at runtime. Fully automatically by the CLR, the chunk of code you don't have right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hans Passant already stated: you **must** compile your C++/CLI code as Dynamic Library in order to be able to consume it from an unmanaged application. CLI/Managed code cannot run from/cannot reside in static libraries.
If you change the C++/CLI library target from Static library to Dynamic library you'll be able to compile successfully your unmanaged C++ application.

One thought from my side:
I think you'll be better if you use mixed mode C++/CLI DLLs to consume the managed functionality - you'll be able to free your consumer application completely from referencing the CLR.

The Header of such mixed mode Wrapper for your Element class would look like this:

```
#pragma once

#pragma unmanaged

#if defined(LIB_EXPORT)
#define DECLSPEC_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC_CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class ElementWrapperPrivate;

class __declspec(dllexport) ElementWrapper
{
private:
    ElementWrapperPrivate* helper;

public:
    ElementWrapper();
    ~ElementWrapper();
public:
    void ExecuteCommand();
};
```

And the implementation would look like this:

```
#include "ElementWrapper.h"
#pragma managed

#include "Element.h"
#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

class ElementWrapperPrivate
{
public:
    msclr::auto_gcroot<Element^> elementInst;  // For Managed-to-Unmanaged marshalling
};

ElementWrapper::ElementWrapper()
{
    helper = new ElementWrapperPrivate();
    helper->elementInst = gcnew Element();
}

ElementWrapper::~ElementWrapper()
{
    delete helper;
}

void ElementWrapper::ExecuteCommand()
{
    helper->elementInst->ExecuteCommand();
}
```

Then just compile your Element.cpp + ElementWrapper.cpp to a DLL and use the ElementWrapper.h in your unmanaged applications.